# How to manage properties file to handle application having multiple Schema/Database

Tags: git, oracle, liquibase

I have an application which has multiple schemas with different username and password. How can I have my properties file to handle this use case so that I can update changes for all schemas by using a single command?

For example, here is the folder structure of application-

```
app-repo-folder/
    Schema1-folder/
    Schema2-folder/
    Schema3-folder/
    liquibase.properties file
```

Comment: afaik it's not possible to update multiple schemas with multiple users by execution of one command. You would need to execute it multiple times.

Comment: @bilak thanks for confirming! Also any idea how to handle properties file in different environments like dev, uat? Should we have single file or need to have one file each for particular environment...

Comment: That depends how is your migration done. But I wouldn't mix multiple envs in one file, that is risky.